# How to delete part of a filename using bash script

Tags: sh, rename, file-extension

I need to rename all filenames (of varying lengths) in directory that end in ".dat.txt" to just ".txt"

**INPUT:**

> FOO.dat.txt, FOO2.dat.txt, SPAM.dat.txt, SPAM_AND_EGGS.dat.txt

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

> FOO.txt, FOO2.txt, SPAM.txt, SPAM_AND_EGGS.txt

Have been trying to use "rename" but I've never used for this situation before.

```
for f in DIRECTORY'/'*.dat.txt
    do
        rename 's/*.dat.txt/*.txt' *
    done
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: On Windows, `rename *.dat.txt *.txt` does the job. Not sure if it works in `sh` too.

Comment: It sure doesn't. Good to know that would work on Windows side, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
for old in FOO*.dat.txt
do
new=$(echo $old | sed 's/.dat.txt/.txt/g')
mv "$old" "$new"
done
```

Comment: `new=${old%.dat.txt}.txt` would be better than spawning an extra process to run `sed`.

Comment: Sort of a brute force method, but i did use a version of this.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the rename program from the util-linux package installed:

```
rename .dat.txt .txt *.dat.txt
```

But I think you might have the perl version instead:

```
rename 's/\.dat\.txt/\.txt/' *.dat.txt
```

See [this **Linux** Questions wiki page](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Rename) for a brief summary of the two versions.

Comment: This only works on systems that actually have a "rename" installed.

Comment: I admit I have no idea the % of linux machines it's installed on. However, he mentions trying to use rename, so I'm assuming he has it installed. I think both our answers have a place for sure :)

Comment: In `rhel` and derivatives, `rename` is provided by `util-linux` package. This package provides `kill`, `fdisk`, `fsck`, `mkfs` to name a few. However, the construct of the command is subject to number of files in the directories which could potentially become too long. Maybe it is a good idea to use `find`, just in case. Or disable glob expansion :).

Comment: Different implementations of `rename` also have very different syntax.

Comment: Thanks for all the high-quality info, definitely appreciated. @chepner I added an example with the other main version of rename I found.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in FOO*dat.txt; do mv "$i" "${i%%dat.txt}txt"; done
```

Using bash parameter expansion: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal

Or perhaps more elegantly:

```
for i in *dat.txt; do mv "$i" "${i/dat.txt/txt}"; done
```

Comment: The second example is a `bash` extension and may not work in the OP's shell. The first is POSIX-compliant, so should be portable.